# mysql.connector issue with System Error : 32 Broken Pipe

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm using library discord.py and i have issue with mysql.connector.
I use mariadb database for server prefixes but when my bot runs 24/7, it starts throwing these errors

```py
0|PyBot    |   File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/discord/utils.py", line 329, in maybe_coroutine
0|PyBot    |     value = f(*args, **kwargs)
0|PyBot    |   File "/home/pi/PyBotV2/bot/main.py", line 11, in get_prefix
0|PyBot    |     return fetch_prefix(message.guild.id)
0|PyBot    |   File "/home/pi/PyBotV2/bot/cogs/database.py", line 15, in fetch_prefix
0|PyBot    |     cursor.execute(prefix_query, (gid,))
0|PyBot    |   File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mysql/connector/cursor.py", line 551, in execute
0|PyBot    |     self._handle_result(self._connection.cmd_query(stmt))
0|PyBot    |   File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 490, in cmd_query
0|PyBot    |     result = self._handle_result(self._send_cmd(ServerCmd.QUERY, query))
0|PyBot    |   File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 261, in _send_cmd
0|PyBot    |     packet_number, compressed_packet_number)
0|PyBot    |   File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mysql/connector/network.py", line 143, in send_plain
0|PyBot    |     errno=2055, values=(self.get_address(), _strioerror(err)))
0|PyBot    | mysql.connector.errors.OperationalError: 2055: Lost connection to MySQL server at 'localhost:3306', system error: 32 Broken pipe
```

My code for DB connection:

```py
import mysql.connector

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
    host="localhost",
    user="USERNAME",
    password="PASSWORD",
    database="discord_bot"
)

cursor = mydb.cursor()


def fetch_prefix(gid):
    prefix_query = "SELECT prefix FROM servers WHERE id = %s"
    cursor.execute(prefix_query, (gid,))
    prefix = cursor.fetchone()
    return prefix[0]

def add_prefix(gid, prefix = "."):
    prefix_query = "INSERT INTO servers(id, prefix) VALUES (%s, %s)"
    cursor.execute(prefix_query, (gid, prefix,))
    mydb.commit()

def remove_prefix(gid):
    prefix_query = "DELETE FROM servers WHERE id = %s"
    cursor.execute(prefix_query, (gid,))
    mydb.commit()

def update_prefix(gid, prefix):
    prefix_query = "UPDATE servers SET prefix = %s WHERE id = %s"
    cursor.execute(prefix_query, (prefix, gid, ))
```

Comment: Sounds like you need to close and open the connection once in a while in order to avoid a timeout (or a broken pipe). Try using a polling mechanism.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A different solution using sqlite3

```py
import sqlite3

path = "discord_bot.db"
conn = sqlite3.connect(path)
cursor = conn.cursor()

def database_interaction(data):
    cursor.execute("SQL Script", (data,))
    result = cursor.fetchone()
    return result[0]
```

Comment: Using a different DB is a very radical solution IMO

Answer (score 2):

> Old connections will time out eventually on the server side, and become unusable.

Try and connect to the server whenever you interact with the database. Or create a timer and reload the connection every so often

Maybe something like this:

```py
import mysql.connector

def connect():
    mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
        host="localhost",
        user="USERNAME",
        password="PASSWORD",
        database="discord_bot"
    )

    return mydb.cursor()

def database_interaction(data):
    database = connect()
    database.execute("SQL Script", (data,))
    result = database.fetchone()
    database.close()
    return result[0]
```

Comment: For the example, shouldn't it be `database().execute("SQL Script", (data,))` instead of `connect().execute("SQL Script", (data,))`?. And would `database().commit()` work after deleting or inserting something in DB?

Comment: Yeah you're right, I changed the name of the function and forgot to update it. As for committing with deleting or inserting, it should work the same as long as your account has permissions

Comment: Also I don't exactly know what you're using the database for, but you could just create and use and offline local database, then there would be issue connecting to it, it would also be quicker

Comment: By offline database you mean sqlite or something like that?

Comment: Actually, when you do `result = cursor.fetchone()`, cursor isn't object so i don't think it will work

Comment: Exactly! sqlite3 is what I use for offline databases

Comment: Honestly you'll need to forgive me, I fixed up the code should work now

Comment: `ReferenceError: weakly-referenced object no longer exists`
This is weird. Could the reason for this be my database server?

Comment: Nope that's a separate issue, when you create a new connection you need to kill the existing ones. You'll need to add `database.close()` at the end of all the database interaction functions (before return though)

Comment: That didn't work but! I came with another solution. From the function database i return just the object and in the functions separatly i create the cursor

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227592/discussion-between-judev1-and-kuba-kropacek).